# Round up if negative round down if positive php?

Tags: php

Round up if negative round down if positive?
I have

`$rounded =1000`

```
39528,65 round should be --> 39000
```

AND

```
-30965,77 --> -31000
```

Comment: Your examples show you rounding down both times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a try with :

```
$rounded = 1000;
foreach(array(39528.65, -30965.77) as $num) {
  echo $num,' -> ', floor($num/$rounded)*$rounded,"\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
39528.65 -> 39000
-30965.77 -> -31000
```

Comment: are sure the result as what u said

Comment: @IEnAk: 19528.65 gives me 19000

Comment: sorry ,I miss understanding with input.you are right ,thankss

Answer (score 6):

use

#### UPDATE

```
$value= ($number>0)  ? floor($number) : ceil ($number);
```

reference
1. [**floor**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)
2. [**ceil**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

Comment: Not if you want to round up :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect as it doesn't round 39528.65 to 3900

Answer (score 0):

Here is the anser that produces correct results as per the specifications of the question.

```
$numbers = [39528.65, -30965.77]; 

foreach ($numbers as $num) 
{
  $rounded = $num > 0 && ($num % 1000) > 0 ? floor($num / 1000) * 1000 : floor($num / 100) * 100;
  print $num. ' is rounded to => '.$result.$rounded.'</br>';
}
```

Output:

39528.65 is rounded to => 39000

-30965.77 is rounded to => -31000

Answer (score -1):

You can use [abs](http://php.net/abs) to get the absolute value, like so:

```
round(abs(-30965,77))
```

If your number is a negative, `abs` will return a positive. Otherwise it will return the positive number. You can then use `round` (with your desired precision) to round your value.

Answer (score -1):

A direct int cast seems do this job, if your rounding up/down means floor/ceil

```
echo (int)( 8.5/8); //  1 = floor( 8.5/8)
echo (int)(-8.5/8); // -1 =  ceil(-8.5/8)
```